# solr 4.0 beta ping response

Tags: solr, jetty

I have the latest solr 4.0.0 beta running with two cores. The solrconfig.xml files for each are practically identical. In the admin UI when I make a ping request for each, I get different results. Here is the setup in a nutshell:

ping config for both solrconfig.xml:

```
    <requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
      <lst name="invariants">
        <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
      </lst>
      <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="qt">standard</str>
        <str name="echoParams">all</str>
        <str name="df">text</str>
      </lst>
    </requestHandler>
```

I am accessing the admin UI with my chrome browser. The ping request for the first core is requested via the url (the domain in the url resolves to my localhost IP):

`http://solr:8983/solr/core1/admin/ping?wt=json&ts=1347035067191`

with the following response:

{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":29,"params":{"echoParams":"all","df":"text","echoParams":"all","ts":"1347035067191","wt":"json","q":"solrpingquery","distrib":"false"}},"status":"OK"}

The ping request for the second core is done via:

`http://solr:8983/solr/core2/admin/ping?wt=json&ts=1347036906643`

with the following response:

{"status":"OK"}

Notice how the second response is missing the responseHeader. The ajax ping response callback is dependent on that responseHeader. The following Error is emitted by the browser due to it (i.e. responseHeader.QTime) being missing:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'QTime' of undefined ping.js:53
$.ajax.success ping.js:53
jQuery.Callbacks.fire require.js:3099
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith require.js:3217
done require.js:9452
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback
```

Am I missing some trivial configuration somewhere that is causing this?

Comment: When I check the manual, it states that admin requests aren't coupled to a core, so I find it strange yours works with the core part of the url.  Mine isn't even working at all on the URL's I try, even though it looks configured.  I'm on 3.6.1 however.

Comment: What does the error log say? Usually when I cant access the admin UI, its due to a misconfiguration in solrconfig.xml or schema.xml

Comment: I tested this and for me too, asking a status without the core in the url fails, but when I add one of the cores, it works.  This is not what I read from the manual